# Why is the network not reachable while another IP is reachable within the same subnet on CentOS?

Tags: centos, centos7, centos6, route, static-routes

Why is the network not reachable while another IP is reachable within the same subnet ?

**Network Reachable**

```
[root@vcn03 ~]# ping -I eth0 -c 1 10.52.96.48
PING 10.52.96.48 (10.52.96.48) from 10.52.111.3 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.52.96.48: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.248 ms

--- 10.52.96.48 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.248/0.248/0.248/0.000 ms
[root@vcn03 ~]#
```

**Network not reachable**

```
[root@vcn03 ~]# ping -I eth0 -c 1 10.52.96.45
PING 10.52.96.45 (10.52.96.45) from 10.52.111.3 eth0: 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.52.96.45 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

[root@vcn03 ~]#
```

**route table of the machine [10.52.96.48] which is reachable**

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.10.92.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em4
10.52.96.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 em4
0.0.0.0         10.52.96.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
$
```

**route table of the machine [10.52.96.45] which is not reachable**

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
172.16.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em2
10.52.96.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
10.52.96.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.248.0   U     0      0        0 em4
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1003   0        0 em2
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1005   0        0 em4
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1006   0        0 bond0
0.0.0.0         10.52.96.1      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
$
```

Comment: On the .45 node you have route rule for 10.52.96.0 network twice (on different NICs) and with different netmask than on .48 node.